# Embedded php and mini.css framework?

Tags: php, css, mini.css

I started developing a web project using the [mini.css framework](https://minicss.org) : [my webpage](http://www.egloff.eu/apaguard_mini/index.php)

I can't make the `<header>` menu or forms to work with all devices. They are not responsive when using some embedded php code.

Can someone confirm this and give me another css framework that works in such conditions ?

Here's my code so far:

```
    <head>
    <title>Apaguard</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>       
    <script src="include/highcharts/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="include/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="include/highcharts/exporting.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/mini-default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/apaguard.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<header class="sticky">
<div class="col-sm col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

    <a href="index.php" class="logo"><img src="./icons/bee-logo.png" height="40" width="40"></a>
    <label class="drawer-toggle button" for="navigation-toggle"></label>
    <a href="index.php" role="button">Home</a>

     <?php
    // if admin access to admin menu
    if ( isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin']=='1' )
    {
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminusers.php' role='button'>Gestion utilisateurs</a>";
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminapaguard.php' role='button'>Gestion Apaguards</a>";
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminruchers.php' role='button'>Gestion ruchers</a>";
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminruches.php' role='button'>Gestion ruches</a>";
    }

    // if logged, access to user menu   
    elseif ( isset($_SESSION['proprietaire_id']) )
            {
                echo"<a href='apaguard_edituser.php' role='button'>Mon compte</a>";
                echo"<a href='change_password.php' role='button'>Password</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_editruche.php' role='button'>Ruches</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_editrucher.php' role='button'>Ruchers</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_editapaguard.php' role='button'>Apaguards</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_datas.php' role='button'>Données</a>";
            }
        else
    {
    echo"
    <a href='apaguard_graph.php' role='button'>Demo</a>
    <a href='apaguard_tech_infos.php' role='button'>Techniques</a>

    ";
    }       
    // dynamic login menu
            if ( !isset($_SESSION['proprietaire_id']) )
                {
                    echo"<a href='login.php' role='button'>Login</a>";
                }
            else 
            {
                echo "<a href='logout.php' role='button'>Logout</a>";
            }
        // if not logged, display visitor menu
    ?>
</div>
</header>
<input type="checkbox" id="navigation-toggle">
<nav class="drawer hidden-md hidden-lg">
<label class="close" for="navigation-toggle"></label>
<a href="index.php"><h4 style="margin-left: 0;">Home</h4></a>
<a href="paguard_graph.php"><h4 style="margin-left: 0;">Demo</h4></a>
<a href="apaguard_tech_infos.php"><h4 style="margin-left: 0;">Techniques</h4></a>
<a href="login.php"><h4 style="margin-left: 0;">Login</h4></a>
</nav>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Umm..... your question's unclear. You also tagged as php; why? and what exactly do you want us to do here?

Comment: I want to know if this behaviour is normal or not.. I f not, i might have a problem. If yes, i will have to search another framework that works...

Comment: without source code, it's anyone's ball game

Comment: Hi Fred, i added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer of mini.css and this is pretty much the expected behavior. If you want your header links to be hidden on mobile, add the `.hidden-sm` class and re-add them to the `<nav>` element, by applying the `.hidden-md.hidden-lg` classes. This way the links in the header will only show on desktop and on mobile they will be shown only in the menu. Here's a sample:

```
    <head>
    <title>Apaguard</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>       
    <script src="include/highcharts/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="include/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="include/highcharts/exporting.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/mini-default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/apaguard.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<header class="sticky">
<div class="col-sm col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

    <a href="index.php" class="logo"><img src="./icons/bee-logo.png" height="40" width="40"></a>
    <label class="drawer-toggle button" for="navigation-toggle"></label>
    <a href="index.php" role="button">Home</a>

     <?php
    // if admin access to admin menu
    if ( isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin']=='1' )
    {
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminusers.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Gestion utilisateurs</a>";
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminapaguard.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Gestion Apaguards</a>";
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminruchers.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Gestion ruchers</a>";
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminruches.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Gestion ruches</a>";
    }

    // if logged, access to user menu   
    elseif ( isset($_SESSION['proprietaire_id']) )
            {
                echo"<a href='apaguard_edituser.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Mon compte</a>";
                echo"<a href='change_password.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Password</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_editruche.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Ruches</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_editrucher.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Ruchers</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_editapaguard.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Apaguards</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_datas.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Données</a>";
            }
        else
    {
    echo"
    <a href='apaguard_graph.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Demo</a>
    <a href='apaguard_tech_infos.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Techniques</a>

    ";
    }       
    // dynamic login menu
            if ( !isset($_SESSION['proprietaire_id']) )
                {
                    echo"<a href='login.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Login</a>";
                }
            else 
            {
                echo "<a href='logout.php' role='button' class="hidden-sm">Logout</a>";
            }
        // if not logged, display visitor menu
    ?>
</div>
</header>
<input type="checkbox" id="navigation-toggle">
<nav class="drawer hidden-md hidden-lg">
<label class="close" for="navigation-toggle"></label>
<a href="index.php"><h4 style="margin-left: 0;">Home</h4></a>
<a href="paguard_graph.php"><h4 style="margin-left: 0;">Demo</h4></a>
<a href="apaguard_tech_infos.php"><h4 style="margin-left: 0;">Techniques</h4></a>
<a href="login.php"><h4 style="margin-left: 0;">Login</h4></a>
<?php
    // if admin access to admin menu
    if ( isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin']=='1' )
    {
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminusers.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Gestion utilisateurs</a>";
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminapaguard.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Gestion Apaguards</a>";
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminruchers.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Gestion ruchers</a>";
        echo"<a href='apaguard_adminruches.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Gestion ruches</a>";
    }

    // if logged, access to user menu   
    elseif ( isset($_SESSION['proprietaire_id']) )
            {
                echo"<a href='apaguard_edituser.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Mon compte</a>";
                echo"<a href='change_password.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Password</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_editruche.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Ruches</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_editrucher.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Ruchers</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_editapaguard.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Apaguards</a>";
                echo"<a href='apaguard_datas.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Données</a>";
            }
        else
    {
    echo"
    <a href='apaguard_graph.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Demo</a>
    <a href='apaguard_tech_infos.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Techniques</a>

    ";
    }       
    // dynamic login menu
            if ( !isset($_SESSION['proprietaire_id']) )
                {
                    echo"<a href='login.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Login</a>";
                }
            else 
            {
                echo "<a href='logout.php' role='button' class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Logout</a>";
            }
        // if not logged, display visitor menu
    ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly !
I can now continue using your nice framework !